# Architecture for http client

Tags: java, android

I am developing application, with http client, and I wonder to make some elegant issue.
This is standard java http client whose work in background thread, and passing data by event's (witch realized by override methods). I have special class for background requests, that implements method sendRequest()

```
protected void sendRequest(final String url)  {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                URI website = null;
                try {
                    website = new URI(url);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(website);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = client.execute(request, httpContext);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                if (response != null)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    try {
                        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                        if (Debug.isDebuggerConnected()==true)
                        {
                            String data = convertStreamToString(is);
                            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();                          
                            if (httpEvent!=null)
                                httpEvent.HttpResponseArrived(data, code);
                        }
                        else
                            httpEvent.HttpResponseArrived(convertStreamToString(is),response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                        }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

And also child class, for API to web server, wich have methods like that:

```
public void getSomeData(SomeParams param)
    {
        sendRequest("http://xxx.yy"+gson.toJson(param));
        httpEvent = new HttpHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void HttpResponseArrived(String data, int code)
            {
                switch (code)
                {
                    case 200:
                        //some code
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        //some code
                        break;

                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And my question: how elegant to handle server errors, for example 401? I need to do this in one place, in method that sending requests - sendRequest(). At first sight it is very easy: just handle 401, and if it's because expired cookie - call method Login() (in my design, it's look like getSomeData). But I want, not just login again, I need to request data, that I failed to get because the error. Of course, I can implement calling Login() method in every switch, like this:

```
case 401:
                    {
                        Login(CurrentContext.AuthData.Login, CurrentContext.AuthData.Password);
                        break;
                    }
```

But the login event implemented in Login() method;
Also, I can just write sendRequest(string authdata), subscrube for HttpHandler and by recursion call method thats implements this code. But I thind, it's not very good decision.
I really hope, that somebody already solve this problem, and there is the way, to turn it's in beautiful code!
Thanks, if you could to read this to the end:)

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to use robust and tested http client framework? EG. HttpApacheClient? - I am widely using that one for any HTTP communications.

Comment: Does it solves my problem? Could I easy control requests states? For example, situation when my request didn't returned data becouse of 401 error, and I need to authorize befor making request again?

Comment: Ofcourse! Read the docs and api. It is complete http client for Java. If you lern it you will love it.

Comment: I am using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for answer not comment.
Try to use http client framework - I prefer Apache HTTPClient. It provides wide controll over request and responses. Moreover it supports most common methods like GET POST etc. Cookie management, redirection handling and SSL support is also provided. Don't invent something that is already invented. 
[HttpClient - use v4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)